# Список Python и два файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как добавить строку из первого файла Python в другой файл

Например:
Во втором файле стоит:

```
a=[]
```

А в первом стоит:

```
from ty import a
x = (15/5)*3+1
a.append(int(x))
```

Как сделать так, чтобы это значение x **сохранялось** в списке и было видно во втором файле?

Comment: Открыть файл, считать весь текст, найти нужное место, вставить нужный текст, сохранить, закрыть.

Comment: Показанный вами код делает именно то, что вы хотите. Никаких дополнительных действий не требуется.

Comment: @andreymal так он ничего и не сохраняет в этот список. Вот в чем беда

Comment: @andreymal Не делает. Нужно, чтобы вместо ``a=[]`` в файле стало ``a=[10]`` (я так понял задачу).

Comment: @V.Bychkov я только что запускал этот код, и всё отлично сохраняется. В файле `ty.py` добавьте функцию вида `def print_a(): print(a)` и запустите её после выполнения `a.append` — вы увидите, что содержимое `a` печатается и что всё прекрасно сохранилось.

Comment: @Эникейщик про то, что нужно сохранять **в файл**, в вопросе не сказано ни слова :)

Comment: Зачем вообще такая хитрая процедура? Очень похоже на [проблему XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @andreymal "чтобы было видно во втором файле".

Comment: @Эникейщик функция `def print_a(): print(a)` отлично видит содержимое списка `a` именно во втором файле. Про то, что значение нужно сохранить в файл на постоянно в файловой системе, повторюсь, в вопросе не сказано ни слова

Comment: И да, это всё к тому, что вопросы нужно грамотно и понятно формулировать :)

Comment: @V.Bychkov, как я понял в `ty` есть переменная с списком, например `a = [1, 2]` Вы хотите из другого скрипта изменить список в файле, чтобы в коде `ty` после стало, например `a = [1, 2, 10]`?

Comment: @gil9red да, именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблем не должно быть если список будет простым, но могут возникнуть проблемы при вложенных списках.

---

Пусть `ty.py`:

```
items = []
print(items)
```

А второй файл:

```
from ty import items
import re

x = (15/5)*3+1
items.append(int(x))
print(items)

# Считаем файл
with open('ty.py', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# Заменим список на другой и сохраним
with open('ty.py', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    pattern = re.compile(r'(items = \[.*?\])')
    new_text = pattern.sub('items = {}'.format(items), text)
    f.write(new_text)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

**main.py**

```
from ty import a


x = (15/5)*3+1
a.append(int(x))
```

**ty.py**

```
a = []

from main import a


print(a)

#10
```

Comment: Мсье знает толк в извращениях)

Comment: но ведь работает)